# calling an activity without any click event - android

Tags: android, android-layout

Iam an newbie to android.I don't know whether this question may sound silly but i didn't find any solution.Please bare me. **I had created an application which will first loads the app logo. I need to call another activity after this without using any click event**.can anybody help me out wit this? and also i need to know in windows we can place panels over another panel. Can we do the same ting android? If yes how can i achieve that? **I know that in a layout we have to place views but my questions is can we design view over another view so that i can hide and show views whenever needed?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't post multiple questions in one question. You should split this into two questions

Comment: You should start with some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Timers or Threads is a horrible way to do this, you are inviting memory leaks into your app. Use Android's Handler instead:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // create Intent for next activity and call startActivity with it
        }
    }, 2000);
```

If you have a reference to your content view, use contentView.getHandler() instead of creating a new one.

By the way, if this is for a personal project, consider [NOT USING SPLASH SCREENS](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)

Answer (score 0):

You do not really provide enough information to give you a proper answer, but this will start a timer and when 5000 milliseconds has elapsed it will switch to another activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private Timer t;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);




Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(WelcomePage.this, HomePage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

that should do the trick my friend!!